# bash associative arrays--variable containing value pair

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, associative

I have a file that looks like this:

```
stringtests (6 tests)
alphatests (1 tests)
arraytests (100 tests)
```

I can extract and translate into:

```
["stringtests"]="6"
["alphatests"]="1"
["arraytests"]="100"
```

I place these in a variable ("tests"):

```
~> tests="[\"stringtests\"]=\"6\" [\"alphatests\"]=\"1\" [\"arraytests\"]=\"100\""
```

Then I try to put them in an associative array using the variable I get an error:

```
~> declare -A arr=( $tests )
-bash: arr: ["stringtests"]="6": must use subscript when assigning associative array
-bash: arr: ["alphatests"]="1": must use subscript when assigning associative array
-bash: arr: ["arraytests"]="100": must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

"eval" doesn't work either:

```
declare -A arr=( $(eval echo $tests) )
-bash: arr: [stringtests]=6: must use subscript when assigning associative array
-bash: arr: [alphatests]=1: must use subscript when assigning associative array
-bash: arr: [arraytests]=100: must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

But, if I put the values directly it works:

```
~> declare -A arr=( ["stringtests"]="6" ["alphatests"]="1" ["arraytests"]="100" )
~> echo ${arr[@]}
1 100 6
~> echo ${!arr[@]}
alphatests arraytests stringtests
```

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Need eval before declare not in the subshell.`eval declare -A arr=( $tests )`. Fails because `=` is evaluated before variable expansion so array sees `["stringtests"]="6"` as a single string.

Comment: @123, eh? `eval` can be avoided entirely here, and when it *can* be avoided it *should*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Just pointing out the issue with their command, not suggesting it was the best option.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
declare -A arr=( $tests )
```

with

```
declare -A arr='('$tests')'
```

---

```
tests="[\"stringtests\"]=\"6\" [\"alphatests\"]=\"1\" [\"arraytests\"]=\"100\""
declare -A arr='('$tests')'
declare -p arr
```

Output:

```
declare -A arr='([alphatests]="1" [arraytests]="100" [stringtests]="6" )'
```

Comment: probably safer to write `declare -A arr="($tests)"` so that the variable is quoted.

Comment: @Cyrus How does escaping/quoting the parenths make it interpret the contents differently? Is there any documentation or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @123: There are no details known to me.

Comment: @Cyrus Did you just stumble upon it then? I can't see why it would make any difference. Why would the `=` be interpreted only if  `()` are escaped?

Comment: @123: I stumbled upon it when I was looking at the output of: `declare -p arr`.

Comment: @Cyrus fair enough!

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the temp variable altogether, and populate the array while you're parsing the file

```
declare -A arr
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    # bash regex: the literal bits are quoted
    if [[ $line =~ (.+)" ("([0-9]+) ]]; then 
        arr["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"]="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done < file
declare -p arr
```

```
declare -A arr='([alphatests]="1" [arraytests]="100" [stringtests]="6" )'
```